# Showing that there is a linear application given its kernel and and image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Consider the following subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$:
> $W=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3:x+y+z=0\}$;
> $V=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3:x=y=z\}$
> Show that there is a linear application $f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ such that $Ker(f)=V$ and $Im(f)=W$.

I found a basis for $W$ and for $V$. Since $ dim(V)=1$ and $dim(W)=2$, $dim(V)+dim(W)=3=dim(\Bbb R^3)$.

Do I need to do anything else? Or is that a good enough justification?

Thank you.

Edit:

I am now trying to explicitly constuct the linear application.

$W=<(-1,1,0),(-1,0,1)>$ , $V=<(1,1,1)>$. $(-1,1,0),(-1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are linearly independ and therefore form a basis of $\Bbb R^3$. We also know that $f(1,1,1)=(0,0,0)$. I tried $f(-1,1,0)=(-1,1,0)$ and $f(-1,0,1)=(-1,0,1)$. I then wrote the matrix of the linear transformation:

Let $B=((-1,1,0),(-1,0,1),(1,1,1))$. Let $B_c=((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1))$

Then I found the matrix to change from basis $B_c$ to $B$

$$M(Id; B_c, B)$$

Then $$M(f; B, B_c).M(Id; B_c,B).\left( \begin{matrix} 
x \\ 
y \end{matrix} \right)$$ gives us the coordinates of $f(x,y)$ in $B_c$.

By doing this, I found a linear application that satisfies the initial conditions:

$f(x,y,z)=1/3*(2x-y-z,-x+2y-z,-x-y+2z)$

Comment: You could also show that basis elements from W and V are linearly independent to explicitly construct the linear transformation

Comment: @FormerMath Thank you. I'll try to do so! I'll update soon

Comment: @FormerMath I've shown the vectors are linearly independent but I'm having  a hard time constructing the linear transformation. Can you maybe give me a hint on how to do so? Thanks

Comment: @FormerMath I've managed to do so! thank you for your help